# How do I sort a text file in python?

Tags: python, sorting

I have a text files which contains  3 scores for each student.

```
"Elizabeth, 2, 7, 3, Anna, 9, 6, 4, Jenny, 8, 1, 5, Victoria,  1, 4, 6"
```

I need to import these results and have them separated by commas. I also need to sort them by:

> average score, highest to lowest
>
> alphabetically, showing each student's high score
>
> highest score to lowest score

Can anyone help me?

Here is what I've done so far however I'm not sure this is the correct way:

```
Class1 = " Jenny, 8, 1, 5, Elizabeth, 2, 7, 3,  Anna,  9, 6, 4 , Victoria,  1, 4, 6"

Listofresults = Class1.split(",")

print (Listofresults)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what exactly is the problem with it? We aren't here to write what is probably your GCSE coursework for you.

Comment: I've tried to split the file.

Comment: i suggest use `json`! with `json.dumps` you can store a dictionary as string and with `json.loads()` you can convert string to dictionary.! sorting list of dictionary is very very easy

Comment: So they can be separated by commas.

Comment: Kindly attach the exact format as how the text is being stored in the text file , then is would be easier to extract relevant data

Comment: This is what I did so far:

Comment: Class1 = " Jenny, 8, 1, 5, Elizabeth, 2, 7, 3,  Anna,  9, 6, 4 , Victoria,  1, 4, 6"
Listofresults = Class1.split(",")
print (Listofresults)

Comment: I am struggling with how to sort the names alphabetically with the highest score for each student. As you can tell I'm quite inexperienced with python. I've researched the different functions that I could use but I've been quite stuck.

Comment: Just did right now. @PM2Ring

Comment: Have you read the [Sorting HOW TO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) in the Python docs? See especially the section about Key Functions.

Comment: @Zaaferani I'm not quite sure how to do that. Could you give me an example?

Comment: No I will look at it right now, thank you. @PM2Ring

Comment: Is the data in your input file all on one line, or are the results for each student on separate lines?

Comment: They were all in one line @PM2Ring

Comment: Which version of Python are you using?

Comment: I'm using 3.3.0 @PM2Ring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't write the whole program for you, but this should get you started. It shows one approach to splitting and storing the input data, and it shows a few ways to sort it. I'll let you figure out how to print the data in the exact format requested.

```
class1 = " Jenny, 8, 1, 5, Elizabeth, 2, 7, 3,  Anna,  9, 6, 4 , Victoria,  1, 4, 6"

#Split on commas and then remove leading and trail spaces
data = [word.strip() for word in class1.split(",")]
print('Input:  ', data)

student_scores = []
for i in range(0, len(data), 4):
    #Get next name & 3 scores 
    name, scores = data[i], data[i+1:i+4]
    #Convert scores in list from string to int
    scores = [int(s) for s in scores]
    #Save the name and scores, with the scores sorted from high to low
    student_scores.append((name, sorted(scores, reverse=True)))

print('Alpha:  ', sorted(student_scores))

def mean_score(student):
    scores = student[1]
    return sum(scores) / len(scores)

print('Average:', sorted(student_scores, key=mean_score, reverse=True))
```

**output**

```
Input:   ['Jenny', '8', '1', '5', 'Elizabeth', '2', '7', '3', 'Anna', '9', '6', '4', 'Victoria', '1', '4', '6']
Alpha:   [('Anna', [9, 6, 4]), ('Elizabeth', [7, 3, 2]), ('Jenny', [8, 5, 1]), ('Victoria', [6, 4, 1])]
Average: [('Anna', [9, 6, 4]), ('Jenny', [8, 5, 1]), ('Elizabeth', [7, 3, 2]), ('Victoria', [6, 4, 1])]
```

I suppose that the trickiest part of this program is the final `sorted()` call, where I've used my `mean_score` function as the key function. If you've read the docs I linked to that should make sense, but if you need further explanation please let me know.

Comment: Thank you so much. This has been really helpful and I feel much more able to complete the whole program. I appreciate your help. @PM2Ring

Comment: How do I do that? @PM2Ring